# Is it secure to use a controller, module or action name to set include paths?

Tags: security, zend-framework

I want to set up include paths (and other paths, like view script paths) based on the module being accessed.  Is this safe?  If not, how could I safely set up include paths dynamically?  I'm doing something like the code below (this is from a controller plugin.)

```
public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {

    $modName = $request->getModuleName();
    $modulePath = APP_PATH.'/modules/'.$modName.'/classes';
    set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.$modulePath);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether it is safe or not, but it doesn't sound like the best practice. What if someone entered a module name like `../admin/`? You should sanitize the module name before using it.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine as long as you sanitize your variables before using them, but it won't be very performant. Fiddling with include paths at runtime causes a serious impact performance.

You're trying to load models/helpers per module? You should look at [`Zend_Application`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.html):

> `Zend_Application` provides a bootstrapping facility for applications which provides reusable resources, **common- and module-based bootstrap classes** and dependency checking. It also takes care of setting up the PHP environment and **introduces autoloading by default**.

*Emphasis by me*

Comment: That's a good idea, but my file structure isn't standard and it's going to take a bit of work to extend the module bootstrap to suit my needs.  Doesn't dispatchLoopStartup() happen before any action controllers are loaded?  I could add it to routeShutdown() instead.  I'm not sure when the runtime begins...

Comment: What I mean is, Zend uses set_include_path() in most of the examples, and the bootstrapping classes/resources will definitely set the paths after the scripts start.